# How to get started with OCaml on VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ocaml

I started learning OCaml several days ago. I installed everything and tested a small program on Atom which worked ok.
But I don't really understand how to work on VSC. I created a file 'test.ml',but how can I run it ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ocamllabs.ocaml-platform?

Comment: Have you tried this blog post? https://sookocheff.com/post/ocaml/starting-a-new-ocaml-project-using-dune-and-visual-studio-code/
It might be a little bit outdated, so take a look also at the main page of the  vscode-ocaml-platform project https://github.com/ocamllabs/vscode-ocaml-platform

Answer (score 5):

Assuming VSC is Visual Studio Code (and you're on a Unix-like system):

If you want editing support such as auto-completions, you need to install OCaml Platform extension for VS Code by following installation steps outlined [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ocamllabs.ocaml-platform). Note that the instructions indicate that you need to also have [`ocaml-lsp-server`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-lsp) installed.

If you need to run `test.ml` as a program, you should do in the VS Code terminal:

```sh
$ ocamlc -o test test.ml # compile 'test.ml' into an executable 'test'
$ ./test # to run the program
```

Note that VS Code doesn't have a ready button to run an OCaml file as an executable (not yet at least).

Newcomers to OCaml are recommended to explore language either with `ocaml` or [`utop`](https://github.com/ocaml-community/utop) REPL.

How to get `utop`: Assuming you have [`opam`](https://opam.ocaml.org/) installed, you should `opam install utop`. Aforementioned `opam` is a package manager for OCaml, that can also help you manage OCaml versions and is indispensable if you want to get serious about OCaml development.

Then you'll be able to launch `utop` in terminal, and inside utop, you can execute `test.ml` with

```sh
#use "test.ml"
```

assuming that `utop` was launched from the folder containing `test.ml`.

You should be able to do the same with `ocaml` REPL that is installed along with OCaml compiler, but it's much less convenient.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I already installed everything you mentioned, just didn't know how to run my code. It works if I type ocaml or utop.

Comment: it it possible to auto add ;; when sending sections of selected text into internal terminal with utop?